# Flash AS2 loading XML from php script

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

i have this problem
I have a Flash application that needs to read an xml file which is dinamically generated by a php script. The swf and html files are on a different server with respect to the php script
I use the xml object and this is the piece of code:

```
var _xml:XML = new XML();

_xml.ignoreWhite = true;

_xml.onLoad = function(success) {
    .....
};
_xml.load("http://PATH_TO_SERVER.do-xml.php");
```

but nothing happens...
The strange thing is that when I launch the `.exe` from my pc, from whichever location, data are correctly loaded and shown.
What's wrong? And why the two different behavoiur?
P.s.: i have no access to the server where resides the php code. i can only 'view' the result as in the attached image.
Thanx a lot
Diego
[image]

Comment: The server hosting the XML data needs a crossdomain file.

Comment: hi Marty, thanks for your answer and sorry for my late...it's been xmas time...

Comment: hi Marty, thanks for your answer and sorry for my late...it's been xmas time...
i followed your suggestion but it didnot work; perhaps i have to ad more details
1. both the php script generting the xml and the flash movie do not reside on the root (it is something like www.site1.it/folder1/setxml.php and www.site2.it/folder2/movie.html)
2. the swf that calls the xml (the php script...) is loaded by the main movie; that is, there is a main swf and from this, i use the loadMovie command to load the swf; the latter calls the php and so on
maybe this double-loading causes the problem?
thanx
diego

Comment: You need to put the cross domain file on the *root* of the server that is producing the XML data.

Comment: ok, i will try again.
i have to add something in the swf? i have read about this command
System.security.allowDomain(...). is it really necessary?